# Import Own mobile Number

Tags: android, phone-number

In my App i want to import my mobile number. I know that phone contact is imported by ContactsContract API but i ma asking for importing own mobile number which is obvious , not present in phone contact detail.

Comment: The sim phone number will be available through a telephony api not through ContactsContract api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handset number is no longer generally available through the telephony API. If you can see the correct phone number in settings -> about phone -> status then yes, you'll get it. But otherwise, no. I have several phones running Android 2.3, 4, 4.1 and 4.2 and none of them show the phone number associated with the SIM card.

Not having the phone number shouldn't be a major headache. I've been working on an SMS application for some time and came to the conclusion several months ago that I just don't need to know the handset number - at all.

If you need the handset number for a good reason then using the Contacts provider you can get access to the device's contact card which may have one or more mobile numbers on it (or none at all!). My suggestion is to use this route to get the available numbers and then ask the user to pick the one that is the handset number, and give them the opportunity to enter a number if it is "none of the above".

If you want to verify that number you could send a text message from the handset to itself or use a text message service to send the handset a message (a bit like having to confirm an email address when creating an account on a web site).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will try your suggestion in my App.

Comment: As always, consider the user's privacy before going down this route. your application needs to have a very, very good reason to need the user's phone number. IMHO information like this has to be central to the application - to the point that without it, the application wouldn't function or would be missing a significant portion of the functionality it would otherwise have.

Answer (score 3):

```
TelephonyManager tMgr
=(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

but be aware it's not guaranteed you get it (so check for NULLs).

Comment: getLine1Number() only guaranteed to get mobile
number if MSISDN number seted for mobile device , we can check from
Setting -> About Phone ->->-> MSISDN.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am really very glad.